# Use of wildcards in Microsoft word to selected text or numbers between round brackets or before a dot

Tags: ms-word, wildcard

Hi I am a complete novice with Microsoft word wildcard function using ctrl h.
So I need some assistance in selecting all sequence text or numbers between round brackets or before a dot, (including the brackets and dots)
.
More specifically I need to select at once,

all sequence Art.227. -, Art.228. -... or

all sequence (1),(2),(3)... or

all sequence a),b),c) or

all sequence 1.,2.,3., or

all sequence (i),(ii),(iii),

which are bolded in the text, as in the following sample:

**Art. 227. -**

**(1)** Banca Naţională a României are competenţa de a aplica sancţiuni administrative, în cazurile în care constată că entităţile prevăzute la art. 223 alin. (1) şi/sau oricare dintre persoanele care exercită responsabilităţi de administrare şi/sau conducere a activităţii de prestare de servicii de plată în cadrul acestora se fac vinovate de următoarele fapte:

**a)** încălcarea prevederilor art. 150-165, art. 218-221, art. 248 alin. (3), a reglementărilor emise în aplicarea acestor articole, precum şi a actelor delegate adoptate de Comisia Europeană în materie de servicii de plată;

**(i)** respectarea imediată a clauzelor contractuale care au fost încălcate;

**(ii)** dispunerea încetării încasării, respectiv restituirea sumelor încasate fără temei legal, într-un termen de cel mult 15 zile calendaristice de la data luării la cunoştinţă a procesului-verbal de constatare a contravenţiei;

**(iii)** aducerea contractului sau tuturor contractelor, după caz, potrivit prevederilor legale, în termen de cel mult 15 zile calendaristice de la data luării la cunoştinţă a procesului-verbal de constatare a contravenţiei;

**b)** nerespectarea măsurilor administrative dispuse potrivit art. 223 alin. (2) lit. c).

**1.** acceptarea operaţiunilor de plată - serviciu de plată prin care un prestator de servicii de plată, în baza unui contract încheiat cu beneficiarul plăţii, acceptă şi prelucrează operaţiuni de plată în scopul transferării fondurilor către beneficiarul plăţii;

**2.** agent - persoană fizică sau juridică care furnizează servicii de plată în numele şi pe seama unei instituţii de plată sau unui furnizor specializat în servicii de informare cu privire la conturi;

**3.** autentificare - procedură care permite prestatorului de servicii de plată să verifice identitatea unui utilizator al serviciilor de plată sau valabilitatea utilizării unui anumit instrument de plată şi care include utilizarea elementelor de securitate personalizate ale utilizatorului;

**(2)** În cazurile prevăzute la alin. (1), Banca Naţională a României are competenţa de a aplica următoarele sancţiuni administrative:

**a)** avertisment scris;

**b)** amendă cuprinsă între 10.000 lei şi 100.000 lei, pentru faptele prevăzute la alin. (1) lit. a) şi b);

**c)** amendă până la de două ori valoarea profiturilor obţinute sau a pierderilor evitate de către persoana responsabilă, în măsura în care acestea pot fi determinate, aplicabilă prestatorilor de servicii de plată;

**d)** suspendarea temporară a dreptului prestatorilor de servicii de plată de a presta servicii de plată până la remedierea situaţiei care a determinat suspendarea;

**e)** suspendarea dreptului de acces la sistemele de plăţi până la remedierea situaţiei care a determinat suspendarea.

**(3)** Sancţiunile administrative prevăzute la alin. (1) pot fi aplicate concomitent cu dispunerea de măsuri administrative potrivit art. 223 alin. (2) lit. c) sau independent de acestea.

**(4)** Amenzile încasate se fac venit la bugetul de stat.

**(5)** Aplicarea sancţiunilor administrative prevăzute la alin. (1) se prescrie în termen de 1 an de la data constatării faptei, dar nu mai mult de 3 ani de la data săvârşirii acesteia.

**Art. 228. -**

**(1)** Constatarea faptelor prevăzute la art. 227 alin. (1) se realizează de către reprezentanţi împuterniciţi ai Băncii Naţionale a României pe baza raportărilor făcute potrivit legii ori reglementărilor emise în aplicarea acesteia sau actelor delegate adoptate de Comisia Europeană în materie de servicii de plată sau la solicitarea expresă a Băncii Naţionale a României ori în cursul verificărilor desfăşurate la sediul profesional sau real al entităţilor prevăzute la art. 223 alin. (1) sau la locaţiile acestora ori la sediile/locaţiile furnizorilor externi în cazul externalizării activităţilor, după caz.

**(2)** Actele prin care sunt aplicate sancţiuni administrative şi sunt dispuse măsuri administrative potrivit prevederilor art. 227 şi reglementărilor emise în aplicarea acestora se emit de către guvernatorul, prim-viceguvernatorul sau viceguvernatorii Băncii Naţionale a României, conform reglementărilor interne, cu excepţia sancţiunilor administrative prevăzute la art. 227 alin. (2) lit. d) şi e), care sunt de competenţa Consiliului de administraţie al Băncii Naţionale a României.

**(3)** Actele prevăzute la alin. (2) trebuie să cuprindă cel puţin elementele de identificare ale persoanei vinovate, descrierea faptei şi a circumstanţelor efectuării acesteia şi temeiul de drept al dispunerii măsurii administrative sau, după caz, al aplicării sancţiunii administrative.

If this is not possible in word, can you help me with regex expressions in notepad++?

Thank you

Comment: As posted, this is not a programming question and, as such, is off-topic for Stack Overflow. Questions on general usage of Microsoft Word should be asked on an appropriate end-use forum (e.g., MS Answers). If it is a programming question, see:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood you well ? Use below code in notepad++ regular expression mode ....

Find:`^\(?\w+[.)].*$`

Replace with: `leave it empty`  or `your desired typing`

Update  `^\(?(\w{1,3})[.)].*$` is a bit more safe